# route pptpd traffic through Tor

Tags: vpn

I have a local Tor server running, and a pptpd server running. I would like it to be able to just connect to my VPN to use Tor (since it will kick back when I leave the house and reconnect when I get there) so that I don't have to reconfigure my internet every time I move.

That, or I could alias a command to set the proxy server, but Tor will not allow outside connections. Could somebody point me in the direction of configuring pptpd to route traffic through Tor or configure Tor to allow outside (non localhost) IP's